# Making Entity Framework generate SQL with column=GetUtcDate()

Tags: entity-framework

Our app runs on many web servers. The time of these web servers can get skewed over time, as is to be expected. The database is a single separate machine with it's own time. We're using EF 5.0 and have a table that needs very precise and consistent times in multiple columns. I would like to be sure the date columns in this table always use the database servers time.

In SQL I would just set the column to GetUtcDate(). Simple, the date is computed and set on the database server, done. But how can I do this with EF on an insert or update? To be clear I need the SQL generated by EF to set the column to the function GetUtcDate() so that the value comes from the database server. I do not want the date being calculated on the web server. Some ideas I've seen and considered and why they don't work for me:

1) I could use default values on the columns in the schema. But I have many update scenarios where I also need consistent dates, not just inserts.
2) I could use triggers in the database. But we currently have zero logic in our database (we are using an ORM after all) and I don't want to set that precedent if I can avoid it. It also is tricky to determine when to update these columns on the database end.
3) I can get the database server time manually (separate query as in the example below), set the column to that value, then do the update. But this is very inefficient as it requires an extra call to the database. In a tight loop this is way too much overhead. Plus the time is now less accurate since I got the time milliseconds earlier, though it is at least consistent.

```
 CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentUtcDateTime()").Execute().First();
```

So what is the right way to do this? Or is it even possible to make EF do the right thing here?

Comment: Normally machines synchronise at least once a day with an NTP server, so they should never be off by more than a second. Do you need higher precision than that?

Comment: Not sure if this helps,but have you seen this [link](http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/06/16/Forcing-Entity-Framework-to-mark-DateTime-fields-at-UTC.aspx).

Comment: Stijn, in theory yes a few seconds a day. In reality I have seen Windows servers be off by dozens of seconds. And yes that accuracy does matter in this case.

Comment: Nilesh, I appreciate the link but it really doesn't address my needs. We are already fully UTC everywhere. Since our servers are cloud based (Azure) and can live anywhere in the world UTC is the only time we can talk in.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really, Can I tell EF to get the Date/Time from the DB / Underlying provider. As far as I know, this isnt possible with EF statements no.
You should use a simple SQL statement prior to the Get DBTime
[T-SQL GetDate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)  Choose the preferred date option

```
        var dq = context.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("select GETUTCDATE();");
        DateTime serverDate;
        foreach (var dt in dq) {
            serverDate = dt;
        }
```

Now use serverDate in your EF linq statement.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts phil. What you are suggesting looks pretty much like my option 3 in my original question. The inefficiency of this (dual db calls) is tough for me to swallow in a tight loop. How confident are you that what I want just is not possible with EF as it stands?

Comment: I have used EF for 18 months and have not seen the option. It could be there. Anyway, I would be interested in why the datetime needs to be collected so often from the server.  I have worked in "exact time" / time critical environments. Im curious as to your concern around the millisecs of going to the DB first when all transactions have the same base ? What is "Exact time" anyway and why it it so critical ?   What the millisec delays server X had over server Y in handling the request ? What makes the moment of update so special ?